Getting "A problem occurred when checking for the updates." Error after upgrading python --version to 3.10 #ubuuntu20
I just upgraded my python version 3.8 to 3.10 for some of my project requirements. After that I am facing the application upgrade or update regarding problem, How can I overcome from the above issue.
Thanks

You've not told us what Ubuntu product & release you're using, but I suggest not changing the default python3 version, especially if using Ubuntu Desktop. All Ubuntu tools that use python3 will expect the version your system came with, and will either stop working OR worse work incorrectly (which can lead to corruption).  You can install many versions, just don't change the default version (or avoid all Ubuntu user-level tools that require python3 to work).  As you've not indicated your product & release, we can only speak generically.

I now note you mention #Ubuntu 20 in the title (that detail belongs in your question or tags; some browser setups don't show title when reading your question!); I'm not familiar with Ubuntu Core 20, but 20.04 esp. Desktop requires python 3.8 to be default; you'll still find base tools (C compiled) will work; but avoid the higher level tools (ie. dpkg should work; apt or higher level may not as they use python3)
